# Select the first 90 characters from the content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am modifying a piece of code, the essence is to pick the first 90 characters from the body of a post. I have managed to get the text including some punctuation characters.

My problem is that I do not know how to get the 90 characters NOT to ignore newline. I want it to terminate once it encounters a line break. As it is now, it doesn't respect it and so ends up adding content from another line/paragraph.

This is the code I am using -

```
$title_data = substr($postdata,0,90);
$title_data = preg_replace("/[^\w#&,\":; ]/",'', strip_tags($title_data));
$data['post_title'] = "F. Y. I - " . $title_data . " ...";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my to cents...  It also makes sure words aren't truncated.

```
// Break the string after the first paragraph (if any)
$parts = explode('</p>', $postdata);

// Remove all HTML from the first element (which contain the full text if no paragraph exists)
$excerpt = strip_tags($parts[0]);

$ending = '...';

if (strlen($excerpt) > 90) {
    // Check where the last space is, so we don't truncate any words.
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 90 - strlen($ending));
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strrpos($excerpt, ' '));
} 


// Return the new string
$data['post_title'] = "F. Y. I - " . $excerpt . $ending;
```

Comment: This worked fine. However for short content with only one paragraph, the problem remained. So what I did was change $parts = explode('</p>', $postdata); to $parts = explode("\n", $postdata); and that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Just be careful.. since you are parsing HTML, a `\n`-sign doesn't mean that there is a new row in the text. And the lack of new line characters doesn't mean there aren't new lines (like `bla bla <br />bla bla`)

Answer (score 1):

The right first step you do the preg_replace(), then you put that value to substr() param.

```
$title_data = preg_replace("/[^\w#&,\":; ]/",'', strip_tags($postdata));
$data = substr($title_data,0,90);
$data['post_title'] = "F. Y. I - " . $data . " ...";
```

Comment: To really help, you should explain what you did and why.

Comment: the first right step you do the preg_replace(), then you put that value to substr() param. Do you get it?

Comment: I get it, others might not.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complicated, but might help to get the result you're after:

```
// Use `wpautop` to work WP's paragraph-adding magic.
$rawText = wpautop($postdata);

// Remove all the opening `<p>` tags...
$preSplitContent = str_replace('<p>', '', $rawText);
// ...and then break into an array using the closing `</p>` tags.
// (hacky, but this gives you an array where each
// item is a paragraph/line from your content)
$splitContent = explode('</p>', $preSplitContent);

// Then run your preg_replace
// (because `$splitContent[0]` is only the first
// line of your text, you won't include any content
// from the other lines)
$firstLine = preg_replace("/[^\w#&,\":; ]/",'', strip_tags($splitContent[0]));

// Then trim the result down to the first 90 characters
$finalText = substr($firstLine,0,90);

$data['post_title'] = "F. Y. I - " . $finalText . " ...";
```

Comment: I seem not to know what is wrong with this solution. It resulted in WP having 500 Error when you try to create a post or edit it.

Comment: Ah sorry - I'd pulled this from an old project and `trimString()` was a function I'd written to automatically add an ellipsis (...) onto the end of a truncated string. Switched it to `substr()` now, so it wont break things.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that.